# Find Instance ID for Azure Servers

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

In AWS we have instance IDs to identify machines. What's the equivalent in Azure and how do I find that?

I'd like to list the instance ID in powershell so I can put that into a script.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood, I suppose you want to get the `InstanceId` of the VM in the Azure VM Scale set.

You could try to use [`Get-AzureRmVmssVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/get-azurermvmssvm?view=azurermps-6.8.1) to get it.

```
Get-AzureRmVmssVM -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -VMScaleSetName <VMScaleSetName>
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to get the `ResourceId` of azure resource, you could use [`Get-AzureRmResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.8.1) to do it, just specify the properties what you want.

For example:

1.Get `ResourceId` of the specific resource:

```
$resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType <ResourceType> -ResourceName <ResourceName> 
$resource.ResourceId
```

2.Get `ResourceId`s of all resources in the specific resource group

```
$resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>  
$resource.ResourceId
```

3.Get `ResourceId`s of all resources under your subscription.

```
$resource = Get-AzureRmResource
$resource.ResourceId
```

The result will like(actual result will decided by your properties):

[image]

Comment: Ok great. How do I find the scale set?

Comment: @bluethundr Have you created the vm scale set?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @bluethundr Could you provide more details about what you want? What the machine mean in your question? May be you want to get the resource id? In Azure, every resource has a resource id.

Comment: yes, I just want something to uniquely identify each machine in Azure, sort of like what you have in AWS with the instance ID. So I guess I want the resource ID if that's what every machine in Azure has.